# setCancelable(true) for AlertDialog.Builder doesn't work as expected on samsung

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I recently discovered that some of the dialogs I implemented in my app work very well, except on samsung devices.

On every device I tested, the "setCancelable(true)" dismissed the dialog when clicking outside of it, except on a samsung devices.

The samsung devices I tested on are : Samsung Galaxy S3, S4 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setCancelable(true) is the exact code.

Anyone else out there that had this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem, for any reason in some devices like Samsung S3 the dialog doesn't disappear doing click out side. You can fix it using setCanceledOnTouchOutside method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
AlertDialog dialog = b.create();
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```

Something like that. I hope to help you.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, i ware suffered form the same problem while testing on the galaxy Grand,
but i noticed that the HTC,Nexus and cyanogenmod behave the same but samsung behave the different as a part of this.

For Fix this problem you have to maintain the Boolean flags, while dialog is exist/showing or not.